# Using the Spring Boot my.url configuration property?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

What is the purpose of the my.url property?  One of the SO questions uses it like this:

```
my.url=http://microservice
```

Does this get us around for example registering `microservice` as a host in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Where is your source that this is a Spring property? This looks like a property that would be used in a tutorial.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265210/eureka-ribbon-loadbalancer-cache-update-delay

Comment: You can put anything in a properties file. This is not a Spring specific property.

Comment: OK - That explains why I have never seen that before ... Thanks